How to insert line breaking penalty in front of math expressions
I would like to avoid that new lines begin with a math expression.
I know the trick that consists in replacing the space just before the math expression with a ~ (unsecable space), like in "text~$a+b=1$".
But I would like to automatize this feature, for instance by automaticaly inserting a huge line breaking penalty in front of each math expression.
Is it possible to do so with a macro (TeX or LaTeX) ? Either during parsing time or just before line breaking algorithm ?
Have you other ideas to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance.
AD

Welcome on TeX.SE. Please can we know your tex code?

I flag this as duplicate of Discourage linebreaks before/after math. While there's no satisfactory answer there, anyone who has a good answer to this question can also post one in that question. If nothing is posted, it seems reasonable to assume the task is hard to do in TeX.
